# Is it possible to extract foreign zip files with 7zip without adding a region to your computer?

Tags: 7-zip

In my 3D modeling circle, many users download and extract zip files from Japanese or Chinese creators. Generally, we are taught to add the relevant regions to our computers to ensure safe text/filename extractions. Some of us use Bandizip to extract because it allows foreign zip-extraction without adding regions, but is this possible with 7zip too? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I have a complete misimpression, but I didn't think that 7zip altered file names or was region dependent (i.e. the main impediment to proper naming would still be Windows).

Comment: @Anaksunaman: The main impediment to proper naming is the software that created the archive. Windows (in general) is Unicode-based, and can accept any Unicode filename regardless of region - but the unarchiving program has to convert the names found in the archive from their "stored" codepage (whatever it is) to Unicode. And the problem is, .zip archives don't say _which_ codepage it originally was...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `.zip` files, 7-zip *does not* have codepage autodetection. It fully understands Unicode-based .zip archives<sup>1</sup>, but if the filename *wasn't* stored as Unicode, then 7-zip will always use the current system's region codepage when extracting (and will result in garbage if the regions don't match). There seems to be no way to tell it to use something else.

If you do not like Bandizip, then WinRAR may work as an alternative – it *does* have an "Options → Name encoding" menu (at least in version 6.00) which can be used to manually specify the correct codepage, e.g. "932 Shift-JIS" for Japanese filenames.

For `.7z` and `.rar` files there should not be any problems, as those formats almost always use Unicode filenames, so their extraction should always work regardless of system region.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unicode support in .zip archives is relatively new<sup>2</sup>; many older programs unaware of the new addition create .zip files with filenames stored in the system codepage. What's worse is that .zip archives have no indication as to *which* region's codepage is being used; the unarchiver is just expected to know (or guess).

I suspect that many of the problematic archives are those that were created through the Windows "Compressed Folders" feature. For a *very* long time it had no Unicode support at all; it would always create and extract archives using the current "region" codepage (e.g. Windows-1257 or Shift-JIS).

This did improve over time; according to my tests, Windows 10 version 1703 was able to extract (but not yet create) Unicode-based Zip archives, and Windows 10 version 21H1 is **finally** creating .zip files with Unicode (UTF-8) filenames.

(Still does it incorrectly and doesn't set the flag that would indicate that the name is indeed stored as UTF-8, but that's a minor issue that most unarchivers will just automatically correct.)

---

<sup>2</sup> 7-zip and WinRAR recognize [all three](https://en.bandisoft.com/bandizip/help/utf8/) methods for storing Unicode names in .zip archives (direct UTF-8; legacy Info-ZIP extra field; and direct UTF-8 with the "UTF-8" indication flag missing).

Comment: Questions: Does the "region codepage" work like a list of assigned regions (hence the add region trick works)? And if `*.7z` and `*.rar` are "always Unicode", does that mean extracting (e.g. JP/CN) zips under that format will (or should) not garble? And is there any rhyme/reason to how the name/contents garbles (e.g. any way to recover)?

Comment: Reprint: It's less that I "don't" like Bandizip that I would rather not have multiple downloaded programs for the same purpose. If I can find a good comparison(s) of the two (+/- other reputable "zipper") and it/they end up favoring Bandizip (or "other zipper"), I may switch...

Comment: 1) I'm not _entirely_ sure what you mean by the "add region" trick. The codepage I'm talking about is also known as "ANSI codepage" or "Language for non-Unicode programs" or "relic from Windows 95/98", and it's not a list -- a Windows system always has exactly one such codepage configured. (The computer wouldn't be able try from a list "until it works", as most codepages work in such a way that decoding text into them _always_ succeeds, and only a human can reliably determine whether the result is correct or not.)

Comment: 2) Generally yes (if by "zips" you meant .rar/.7z archives). 3) In theory yes, the process should be reversible (and a program like 'convmv' could fix it), but depending on various things (the unarchiver, the OS, the legacy codepage that Windows is set to use, the filesystem type...) some information may get irreversibly lost. For example, `ウィキペディア` encoded as Shift-JIS can survive being mis-decoded as CP1251 or CP1252 (resulting in `ѓEѓBѓLѓyѓfѓBѓA` or `ƒEƒBƒLƒyƒfƒBƒA`), but some characters are lost if CP1257 is used. So in some regions it's less likely to be fixable post-factum than others.

Comment: (To be clear, it is almost always fixable _during_ extraction if the program knows how to interpret the stored files, e.g. when Bandizip or WinRAR are told that the original was SJIS, they'll just decode it as SJIS, no problem. The issue I'm talking is if you're trying to fix names _after_ extraction, i.e. after they've already been interpreted wrongly and you have to undo that first.) Also 3) There's a graphical example of how this works at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake#Causes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Contrary to what the chosen answer says, 7-Zip ***does*** have the capability to extract a `.zip` file with compressed file names encoded in different codepages, although not many users are aware of it as it's *undocumented* at least in the help file.
2. The catch is, it's only possible using a command line switch, and the GUI does not offer any menu item or keyboard shortcut.

Open a Command Prompt window or press `Win + R` and use the `-mcp` switch to do it.

e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip-Zstandard\7zG.exe" x -mcp=932 -o"C:\your folder" -- "C:\dn\from a Japanese creator.zip" *

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" x -mcp=1251 -o"C:\your folder" -- "C:\dn\from a Russian.zip" *
```

3. The command line version, `7z.exe` may also be used the same way.
4. `Shameless advertisement follows:` If you often use 7-Zip, consider switching to [7-Zip Zstandard](https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip-zstd). It is fully backward compatible with 7-Zip and provides additional codecs including the [Zstandard codec](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/), which imho is optimal for *everyday use* as it provides **immensely faster decompression** and *slightly better compression ratios* than zip, among other benefits. And no, I'm not affiliated with its author or Facebook. Although I hate to use a fork, I have no other option until the main branch incorporates this codec.